# ClassCast exception when using GoCardless Java library with ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am using the GoCardless Java library with ColdFusion but am getting the following exception:

> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

Having read [this blog post](http://danwatt.org/blog/2012/06/07/making-java-coldfusion-tomcat-and-payflowpro-play-nicely/) it seems that GoCardless is written against javax.net.ssl, but the JVM is dealing with com.sun.net.ssl.

The blog post suggests fixing this by setting the following Java system property:

```
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=javax.net.ssl
```

I am inexperienced with changing JVM settings and wondered if changing the setting above might cause issues elsewhere, perhaps where native ColdFusion methods rely on com.sun.net.ssl? If it is possible that issues might arise then I cannot realistically fix the problem by changing the JVM setting as I have several applications running on the same instance of ColdFusion.

Would there be any other way around this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I do not have an answer for you about issues/incompatibilities. However, I imagine that setting can impact any tag or function capable of making a ssl call, such as `cfhttp`, `cfdocument`, etcetera. (Obviously it would affect all applications using that jvm). You might check the documentation to see if the API offers any mechanism for setting/change the default security provider used (cont'd...)

Comment: Some libraries provide a custom properties file, like the standard [`security.properties`](http://download.java.net/jdk6/beta2/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html). You might also leave the author of the blog entry a comment. Ask if they experienced any issues. Worth a shot ...

Comment: Footnote: a [CFML-specific client library for GoCardless](https://github.com/cfsimplicity/gocardless-cfml) is now available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read your comment on the referenced blog post. In it you asked *is there a way to set -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs to javax.net.sll temporarily and then switch it back to com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol*. I believe there is.

**Disclaimer - I have not attempted this and I am not sure of the ramifications. For example, multiple requests could be running simultaneously while you have changed this setting.**

Read this post - [You *can* set Java system properties via ColdFusion](http://www.stillnetstudios.com/you-can-set-java-system-properties-via-coldfusion/)

So, theoretically, you could change the setting like so:

```
<cfset sys = createObject("java", "java.lang.System")>
<cfset sys.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "javax.net.ssl")>
```

And then change it back (see next example to retrieve the current setting):

```
<cfset sys = createObject("java", "java.lang.System")>
<cfset sys.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol")>
```

You can also read the current system properties like so:

```
<cfset sys = createObject("java", "java.lang.System")>
<cfoutput>#sys.getProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs")#</cfoutput>
```

(Reading that property on my ColdFusion 9.0.1 server returned `com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol`)

Comment: Miguel-F - Unfortunately that is a system wide property too. So it would have the same affect as the jvm flag. I think the property value is actually read from the jvm flag in the OP. Either that or the highest priority provider from `security.properties`. So all of the three ways to set the provider are system wide. AFAIK, it cannot be changed on a per session/application basis, unless the library provides a mechanism for doing so.

Comment: @Leigh - Yes I realize that it is system wide (hence my disclaimer). I was really answering a question that the OP posted on the other blog post. Namely, can you change the setting and then change it back. I tried to bring that to light in my answer but guess I failed...

Comment: Miguel-F : No, my bad. *You* were clear .. I was a bit distracted and when I skimmed and responded ;-) What I should have added was that it is still risky *because* it is a System wide property. There is still the potential to affect other apps on the jvm because [there is no guarantee *when* it will be read](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/garysweaver/archive/2008/08/javaprotocolhan_1.html). That makes me less comfortable using it. (That is why I did not suggest it in the comments).

Comment: +1 @Leigh I agree and almost didn't post as well. I did post so that the OP knows about the option but with my not-very-good disclaimer.